# Deleting two dimensional array use memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this program for quite some time. This is just two of the functions extracted that are causing a memory leak that I cant seem to debug. Any help would be fantastic!

```
   vector<int**> garbage;
```

CODE for deleting the used memory

```
   void clearMemory()
   {
         for(int i = 0; i < garbage.size(); i++)
         {
               int ** dynamicArray = garbage[i];

               for( int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++ )
               {
                   delete [] dynamicArray[j];
               }
         delete [] dynamicArray;
         }
         garbage.clear();
   }
```

CODE for declaring dynamic array

```
   void main()
   {
        int ** dynamicArray1 = 0;
        int ** dynamicArray2 = 0;


        dynamicArray1 = new int *[100] ;
        dynamicArray2 = new int *[100] ;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ )
        {
            dynamicArray1[i] = new int[100];
            dynamicArray2[i] = new int[100];
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                dynamicArray1[i][j] = random();
            }
        }

        //BEGIN MULTIPLICATION WITH SELF AND ASSIGN TO SECOND ARRAY
        dynamicArray2 = multi(dynamicArray1); //matrix multiplication
        //END MULTIPLICATION AND ASSIGNMENT

        garbage.push_back(dynamicArray1);
        garbage.push_back(dynamicArray2);
        clearMemory();
   }
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`, forget about `new []` and `delete []`, and enjoy watching your memory leaks vanish

Comment: @Tushar: That is so wrong... he is using a vector of raw, dynamically allocated pointers. `delete garbage` will only deallocate the memory that the vector allocated *to store the pointers*.  That's why you don't use vectors in this way.  At least use `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`, but even then, why the pointers?

Comment: Nonetheless, I can't see a leak in this code. Does `multi` do anything with memory?

Comment: The leak seems to be that you allocate memory to dynamicArray2, but then overwrite that pointer when you call `multi`. So you have no way of freeing the memory that you allocated to dynamicArray2 originally. The fix may be as simple as not allocating any memory to dynamicArray2 in main but that depends on exactly what is going on in multi. The best fix is to learn how to use vectors instead.

Comment: Do something like `void multi(const int** input, int** output)` instead of returning the array, which is what's causing your issues.

Comment: A `std::vector<>` of raw pointers has very specific use-cases, and resource *ownership* by the pointers is **not** one of them. A sort-bed of pointers to objects in another container is an example of something that *would* fit that usage. I *strongly* suggest you heed Andy's first comment in this list.

Comment: How do you know there's a leak? Is their relevant output you're not providing?

Answer (score 1):

I stared at the code for some time and I can't seem to find any leak. It looks to me there's exactly one `delete` for every `new`, as it should be.

Nonetheless, I really wanted to say that declaring an `std::vector<int**>` pretty much defies the point of using `std::vector` itself.

In C++, there are very few cases when you HAVE to use pointers, and this is not one of them.
I admit it would be a pain to declare and use an `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` but that would make sure there are no leaks in your code.

So I'd suggest you rethink your implementations in term of objects that automatically manage memory allocation.

Comment: Took me a while to spot it but the leak is certainly because the pointer dynamicArray2 is overwritten when the function multi is called. This is automatically a memory leak because the memory previously pointed to by dynamicArray2 cannot now be freed.

Comment: I would only add that, if iteration is a bottleneck, a vector of vectors (of vectors...) is horrible in regards to performance.  Locality of data goes right out the door.  You'd be better off allocating big chunks and using a `vector<unique_ptr<int>>`, calculating the offset to each sub array manually.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: If you have a memory leak, use `valgrind` to locate it. Just like blue, I can't seem to find a memory leak in your code, but `valgrind` will tell you for sure what's up with your memory.

Point 2: You are effectively creating a 2x100x100 3D array. C++ is not the right language for this kind of thing. Of course, you could use an `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` with the obvious drawbacks. Or you can drop back to C:

```
int depth = 2, width = 100, height = 100;

//Allocation:
int (*threeDArray)[height][width] = malloc(depth*sizeof(*threeDArray));

//Use of the last element in the 3D array:
threeDArray[depth-1][height-1][width-1] = 42;

//Deallocation:
free(threeDArray);
```

Note that this is valid C, but not valid C++: The later language does not allow runtime sizes to array types, while the former supports that since C99. In this regard, C is more powerful than C++.